# Why only last TableView instance cells handles mouse events?

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I've created TableView component as below and instantiate it several times. I want to handle mouse events for header/table cells. Problem is that only last instance gets these events. I've played this for hours with `propagateComposedEvents/preventStealing/mouse.accepted` and many others but without any success (tried qt6.5.1 / 6.5.2). Any idea why is this happening? Do you see the same behavior?

```
import QtQuick 6.5
import QtQuick.Controls 6.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.5
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    id: app
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    Component {
        id: testTable

        Rectangle {
            id: control

            implicitHeight: 200
            implicitWidth: 400

            Component.onCompleted: {
                // just fill a table with some data
                tableView.model.appendRow({ value : 10 })
                tableView.model.appendRow({ value : 20 })
                tableView.model.appendRow({ value : 30 })
            }

            ColumnLayout { // Header + TableView

                id: contentLayout

                anchors.fill: parent

                HorizontalHeaderView {
                    id: horizontalHeader

                    Layout.fillWidth: true

                    syncView: tableView

                    model: [
                        qsTr("Value")
                    ]

                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        border.width: 1
                        implicitHeight: 20
                        implicitWidth: 50

                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: (mouse) => {
                                print("Header onClicked")
                            }
                            onPressed: (mouse) => {
                                print("Header onPressed")
                            }
                            onReleased: (mouse) => {
                                print("Header onReleased")
                            }
                        }

                        Text {
                            text: modelData
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                        }
                    }
                }

                TableView {
                    id: tableView

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true

                    model: TableModel {
                        TableModelColumn {
                            display: "value"
                        }
                    }

                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        border.width: 1
                        implicitHeight: 20
                        implicitWidth: 50

                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: (mouse) => {
                                print("Table onClicked")
                            }
                            onPressed: (mouse) => {
                                print("Table onPressed")
                            }
                            onReleased: (mouse) => {
                                print("Table onReleased")
                            }
                        }

                        Text {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            text: model.display
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        Loader {
            sourceComponent: testTable
        }
        Loader {
            sourceComponent: testTable
        }
        Loader { // only the last 'testTable' gets mouse events, why???
            sourceComponent: testTable
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to put the table component in separated file and use simple layout instead of Loader: the result was the same.

Comment: Perhaps you should set width and height of each of your Loaders.

Comment: @StephenQuan nope, it doesn't help